# Pull in SourceTree with no new code in local machine

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I am new using SourceTree (in Bitbucket). I just joined a team for a project. I have not started developing yet but was told to clone master repository into my local machine so I can see and view it before getting assigned a task. I did not create any new branches. I have not done anything in my local machine(no code, no commits ,etc). Since then, the other developers has made new features, branches, and pull requests/merging. Because of this, in SourceTree, there is a number next to the PULL button indicating me to pull. I would love to have these new changes in my local machine. If I do a PULL, will these changes get into my my machine without causing any conflicts?

Basically, I :

1) I just want the new code in my local machine.
2) I don't want conflicts. I have not made any changes or new code in mine but if they did changed a previous code and also wrote new code...will that cause a conflict?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not made any changes, it's definitely safe to do a `git pull`.

If you have uncommitted changes, you can stash them first with `git stash`, and then you can do a `git pull`.